# How to pop up web page element without deleting it after that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with pop up window. I found library that pop up elements of web page. It does it great but after it pops up element, it also deletes it from my web page (which I don't want). [Here is the library that I used](https://raw.github.com/dinbror/bpopup/master/jquery.bpopup.min.js).

Comment: Hint: [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: Hint3: It doesn't remove your element, just sets `display: none`.

Comment: Hint 2: post code YOU actually tried - if it IS a plug-in, show how YOU used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in the code it is not deleted, but simply hidden.

```
default:
        open();
        $('<div class="b-ajax-wrapper"></div>')
            .load(o.loadUrl, o.loadData, function(){
                triggerCall(o.loadCallback);
                recenter($(this));
            }).hide().appendTo(o.contentContainer);
```

So try just removing the `hide()` from the script you're using.
Or use the popup-library on a cloned element, which is therefore not visible on the page anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I just did it in same way, cloning the element.